# tvOS - Nested CollectionView not focusing correctly

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, tvos

I have a nested collection view (outer vertical collection view with inner horizontal collection view as its cell). Focus is moving down properly but for some reason, it is not moving up/right.

I turned off focus for outer collection view based on Apple's sample code.

Code of Outer collection view custom cell that manages inner collection view:

```
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in collectionView: 
   UICollectionView) -> IndexPath? {
    return IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
}

override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
    return true
}

override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    if let v = UIScreen.main.focusedItem as? UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView.indexPath(for: v) != nil {
            return super.preferredFocusEnvironments
        }
    }
    return [collectionView]
}
```

Code of Inner Collection View custom cell (to update focus):

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var posterView: UIImageView!

  override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
    return true
  }

  override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if context.previouslyFocusedView === self {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            context.previouslyFocusedView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }
    }


     if context.nextFocusedView === self {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            context.nextFocusedView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

Focus should move up, down, left or right properly

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the way I created xib file (I directly created new xib with Interface type "View" for CustomCollectionViewCell). Create Cocoa Touch class with xib and delete the not needed cocoa touch class. One other solution is to use storyboard and load CustomCollectionViewCell from it.